# Laravel groupBy return array of items instead of using date for key

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm using the Laravel `groupBy` method to format my data and group them into periods, however, I'd like to change how I return my results. Rather than using the `created_at` as the key for an array item, I don't want there to be a key, and instead, just move that key into the returned result instead...

The following code will return:

```
"results": [
    {
        "2021-03-04": {
            "event_category": "category",
            "event_action": "action",
            "event_count": "544",
            "period_from": "2021-03-04 00:00:00",
            "period_to": "2021-03-04 10:30:02",
            "created_at": "2021-03-04 10:30:06"
        },
        "2021-03-03": {
            "event_category": "category",
            "event_action": "action",
            "event_count": "5337",
            "period_from": "2021-03-03 00:00:00",
            "period_to": "2021-03-03 23:57:03",
            "created_at": "2021-03-03 23:57:08"
        }
    }
]
```

Here's how that looks

```php
$res = DB::table('my_table')
         ->select('event_category', 'event_action', 'event_count', 'period_from', 'period_to', 'created_at')
         ->where([["event_category", "category"], ["event_action", "action"], ["period_from", ">=", "2021-03-01"], ["period_to", "<=", "2021-03-04 22:00:00"]])
         ->orderBy('created_at, 'desc')
         ->get();

$results = $res->groupBy(function ($item, $key) use ($findable) {
  $date = Carbon::parse($item->created_at);
  return $date->format($findable['groupByFormat']);
});

$results = $results->map(function ($item, $key) {
  return $item[0];
});

$res = $results;
```

I'd like to return...

```
"results": [
    [
        "event_category": "category",
        "event_action": "action",
        "event_count": "544",
        "period_from": "2021-03-04 00:00:00",
        "period_to": "2021-03-04 10:30:02",
        "created_at": "2021-03-04 10:30:06",
        "new_created_at": '2021-03-04'
    ],
    [
        "event_category": "category",
        "event_action": "action",
        "event_count": "5337",
        "period_from": "2021-03-03 00:00:00",
        "period_to": "2021-03-03 23:57:03",
        "created_at": "2021-03-03 23:57:08",
        "new_created_at": '2021-03-03'
    ]
]
```

I've tried removing my initial map, but not sure how to achieve such format whilst remaining the grouping

Comment: Did you try Flatten method?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$results = $results->map(function ($items, $key) {
    return array_merge($items, ['new_created_at' => $key]);
})->values();
```

The call to values() on the end just returns the values of the collection so that it is keyed by numbers rather than dates.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#337 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▼
      "event_category" => "category"
      "event_action" => "action"
      "event_count" => "544"
      "period_from" => "2021-03-04 00:00:00"
      "period_to" => "2021-03-04 10:30:02"
      "created_at" => "2021-03-04 10:30:06"
      "new_created_at" => "2021-03-04"
    ]
    1 => array:7 [▶]
  ]
}
```